# No hdmi signal when starting up raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, boot-issues

I'm completly new to raspberry pi and arn't getting any picture on the screen
When I first got my Raspberry pi and set everything up I tried starting it to see if it works and everything worked perfectly but after I took out the sd card and formated it and downloaded an OS following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntaXWS8Lk34&ab_channel=RaspberryPi my raspberry pi didn't show any image on the screen only hdmi no signal. I've tried different monitors,cables, sd cards and I've tried this fix I found on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbwedsfovcM&ab_channel=TroubleChute but that didn't solve my problem so now I'm out of ideas. Anyone that know what could be a solution?

Comment: It is unclear what you have done. Try installing Raspberry Pi OS using the Raspberry Pi Imager tool https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/

Comment: Which Pi? there are many different ones. How long ago did it work? Why did you re-flash the existing card? did it stop working?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.